# How to get an evicted item in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, ignite, in-memory

Is there a way to get an evicted item in Apache Ignite?

I set LRU eviction policy.

I assume that when I put a new key and a value, if the cache space is full, then one item is evicted by LRU eviction policy, and then the new key and value cached.

If it is correct, I wanna know which key and value are evicted.

Is there a way to know that?

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to [EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/events/EventType.html#EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED).
There is a [test](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/GridCacheEvictionEventAbstractTest.java) which shows how to do it properly.